# Parse javascript one to many relations query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

In Parse I have several tables: Restaurant, Party, Payment. A payment belongs to one party which belongs to one restaurant. I want to get all payments for all parties from a single restaurant (which I have access to). How do I go about writing this relationship's query using Parse and Javascript? My attempt so far (which retrieves the correct amount of parties but not the correct number of payments):

```
var Party = Parse.Object.extend("Party");
var partyQuery = new Parse.Query(Party);
partyQuery.equalTo("restaurant", $scope.currentRestaurant);

partyQuery.find().then(function(parties) {
    $scope.parties = parties;

    //payment
    var Payment = Parse.Object.extend("Payment");
    var paymentQuery = new Parse.Query(Payment);

    $scope.payments = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.parties.length; i++) {
        paymentQuery.equalTo("party", $scope.parties[i]);

        paymentQuery.find().then(function(payments) {
            $scope.payments.push(payments);
            $scope.$digest();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log("message");` or did you run it with developer tools and breakpoints?  The code looks very nice.

Comment: I wonder if you could test this with something like Parse-Mock.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-mock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `payments` you get back from `paymentQuery.find()` might be an array right?  Then when you push payments into `$scope.payments`, you are pushing an array into an array.  Is that what you want?  If you are just counting the `$scope.payments` array, maybe that is why it is not the correct count.  You could try this instead:

```
        for (var j = 0; j < payments.length; j++) {
          $scope.payments.push(payments[j]);
        }
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot that. Thank you so much!